# Getting Error: unauthorized_client when trying to authorize script

Tags: node.js, google-api, authorization, jwt, google-api-nodejs-client

I've created service account with domain wide delegation and its scopes (in Admin console and Developer console) as described in documentation. I've been trying this for a week now and I am stuck. This is my code:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const gmail = google.gmail('v1');
const directory = google.admin('directory_v1');
const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
];
const key = require('./service_key.json');

var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  key,
  key.private_key,
  scopes,
  "kruno@example.com"
);

authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

// API call methods here...

});
```

I get this error:

> Error: unauthorized_client

I am unable to understand:

- Is this proper technique for calling Google API methods from server-side scripts without any user interaction? (under domain only)
- How do service account and actual user account communicate this way?
- I heard about callback URI, am I missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the final step which is giving access to your application in the control panel of your domain.

You can follow doc properly to activate it with your application

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation

Also you can start with your first call step here

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call

Comment: I already gave domain wide authority and scopes for this service account. I do not understand which exactly part am I missing?

Comment: how did you fix this @Kunok ?

Comment: @tiagoperes In my case scopes didn't match properly. Can you describe your problem?

Comment: The problem I had was the argument not being the right one. Got fixed already, thank you.

My problem now is ''WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Reddit' '

Comment: Just to let you know, this problem also got fixed. If you stumble accross and don't know what you are doing wrong, check my profile

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation : redirect to 404